# Is there any gem or plugin available in rails 4 which is Generate dynamic form just like google form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anyone suggest me some plugin or gem in rails 4 which is Generate dynamic form just like google form
Actually, I want create form according with field type
I'm really thankful of you
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1nS_mrAMhig-qRBZKAg-M9aTGca1dzNppTciSuFAUtKQ/edit

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jvillian thanks to reply, but I did't get any source of that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for help on what is on-topic for Stack Overflow.